# Transformation behaviour of partial derivatives of vectors in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

It seems to be rather straight-forward calculation, but it is not (neither is this a homework question). Actually I'd like to show that $A_{[i,k]}$ transforms like a tensor in curvilinear coordinates without using a connection (the usual trick is to use the symmetry of the lower indices of the components of the connection, a property which is not guaranteed in case of torsion).

Let's start with the transformation property of $A_{i,k}$.

$$\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^k } = \frac{\partial x^{m'} }{\partial x^k } \frac{\partial  }{\partial x^{m'}}[\frac{\partial x^{l'}}{\partial x^i} A_l']=\frac{\partial x^{m'} }{\partial x^k }\frac{\partial x^{l'}}{\partial x^i}A_{l',m'} + \frac{\partial x^{m'} }{\partial x^k } \frac{\partial^2  x^{l'} }{\partial x^{m'} \partial x^i} A_{l'} $$

We get the additional inhomogeneous term, but actually it is zero, because $\frac{ \partial x^{l'}}{\partial x^{m'}} = \delta^{l'}_{m'}$ and $\partial_i \delta^{l'}_{m'} =0$! This is not the expected result, because it would show that $A_{i,k}$ would transform like a tensor although we know it doesn't. Actually, I expected an inhomogeneous term like $\frac{\partial^2  x^{l'} }{\partial x^{k} \partial x^i}$ or similar, however, I don't know how to get it.
Of course this way I could conclude that $A_{[i,k]}$ transforms like a tensor, but I am sure that the proof is wrong. So what has gone wrong ? I took the transformation rules from Landau/Lifshitz volume 2, formula (83,3) and (83,4).

Comment: What's wrong with the standard approach?  You end up with a term that depends on the torsion tensor, but the torsion tensor is a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be smooth and set $(u,v) = f(x,y).$
Then
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\, \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y\, \partial x},
\quad
\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x\, \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y\, \partial x}
$$
Now something important: Notice that these are still expressions in $x$ and $y$.

So what do we mean when we then take partial derivatives w.r.t. $u$ and $v$?
It means that we first transform our expressions from being in $x$ and $y$ to being in $u$ and $v$. This is done by composing with $f^{-1}$:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
:= \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \circ f^{-1}\right)
$$
Therefore, by the chain rule, we get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \circ f^{-1}\right)
= \left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\circ f^{-1}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \, \partial y}\circ f^{-1}\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial x^{m'} }{\partial x^k } \frac{\partial^2  x^{l'} }{\partial x^{m'} \partial x^i}= \frac{\partial x^{m'} }{\partial x^k }\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{m'} } \left[\frac{\partial  x^{l'} }{\partial x^i}\right]=\frac{\partial^2  x^{l'} }{\partial x^{k} \partial x^i}$ and you have what you want.

The trick is exactly what @md2perpe have written. The $\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^k}$ depends on $x$. By writting $\frac{\partial x^{m'} }{\partial x^k } \frac{\partial  }{\partial x^{m'}}[\frac{\partial x^{l'}}{\partial x^i} A_l']$, you assume you transformed $\frac{\partial x^{l'}}{\partial x^i} A_l'$ to depend on $x'$. So you first compute $\frac{\partial x^{l'}}{\partial x^i}$, then transform the resulting functions into $x'$ coordinates and only then take derivative. Said like this, it should be now obvious the result might not be zero.